# an Open Source graphic software like fireworks

Tags: html, website-design, free, graphics, software

Hi All and happy new year
i'm wondering if there's any open source and free software to create designs, the way fireworks does, by allowing creation of slices (decoupes, HTML and images)
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

try

http://www.gimp.org/ a raster image editor, like fireworks, photoshop, paint shop pro
http://www.inkscape.org/ a vector image editor, like illustrator, draw

there are no alternatives better than gimp & inkscape

they are available for Windows, Linux, Mac

hope this helps!